# How to get Android AudioRecord buffer as number array?

Tags: android, casting, audiorecord

Is there a way to get the AudioRecord buffer as a number array, for example a float array? A simple typecast of the array doesn't seem to work but I didn't find a documentation how the buffer data looks like.

I get the buffer as follows:

```
recorder = new AudioRecord(...);
...
byte buffer[] = new byte[bufferSize];
....
while(isRecording){
      read = recorder.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
      //-->How do I get buffer as number array?
...
```